# Setting up tipc on Trusty

Tags: apt, network-monitoring

I am trying to setup tipc i.e tipcutils.

I would like to use it to monitor my network for clustering, drbd/ocfs2.

It seems the package is currently missing in Trusty although it is referenced upstream at http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tipc.

```
root@downstairs:~# apt-get install tipcutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tipcutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Do I need to download it from http://tipc.sourceforge.net/?

I use this regularly at work, I am a software engineer working for a large telecoms company. We use it with SLES and SAF for clustering/high availability.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is from 2009. From the README of ticputils 2.0.2 it says "Last updated: 04 May 2010".

I seriously doubt that it will compile and work in a modern Linux distribution...

Since Precise, it [was never included in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tipcutils&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

I guess that your best shot is to download it from [the sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tipc/files/tipc-linux-extras/) and hope to be able to compile it (a lot of dependencies might be unresolvable).